# How to use compare word in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-structure, phrases

I would like to write one good sentence about comparing outputs of two models. Here is an example,

This part aims to compare the output of the first model with the output of the second model.

Is this correct? Is there a better way to present my sentence?

Any help, please?

Comment: Why are you concerned that it might not be correct?

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks so much for your comment. That because I repeat the word output.

Comment: @ColleenV Can I say: This part aims to compares the outcome of the first model with the one with the second model.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add more explanation of what your concerns about the sentence are  - there are some examples of questions with good detail here : https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4584/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is correct. If, however, you want a construct similar to your second comment, it will be "This part aims to compare the outcome of the first model with that of the second". Appending "model" at the end is not necessary.